# session['value'] = nil doesn't seem to stay empty in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables

My controller tries to set the session value to nil.  Within the controller, it works, but then we I reload the browser (not quit), the session value comes back?

How can I keep it cleared out and empty?  Is it possible the browser still stores that session even though I set it = nil?

Comment: Are you calling `session['value]' = nil` or `session = nil`?

Comment: the first -- I don't want to kill the other session variables....

Comment: Then the code you provided should be correct. Are you sure it is being called?

Comment: yes, I step through it in the debugger... :(

Comment: I am having this same problem when I set an existing session to a new value.  On reload the original session value is loading.  I think that Kelvin is correct about the new value not making it to the browser, but i don't know why that would be the case.  @Angela, did you ever find an answer to this problem

Answer (score 1):

Setting the variable to nil keeps the session.
Try to call

```
reset_session
```

in your controller to get rid of the whole session.

Nonetheless, even after setting the value to nil, it should not come up in your next request. Make sure you are not setting it back, e.g. in a before_filter.

Comment: I want to keep the session, just that one value.  I use it to check if the person coming came by clicking on an invitation link

Comment: In that case your code is correct, indeed. There must be something else wrong. Could you please provide additional information, such as
- Which session storage do you use (Cookie or ActiveRecord)
- Controller code setting value to nil
- Controller code for checking the value in next request

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cookie store for the session, maybe the changed session isn't making it to the browser. If this is the case, the browser still has the old value in the cookie. When the page is reloaded, the browser will send the cookie to rails, which will restore the old value.

It's hard to say more without seeing your controller action.